# ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Arial" cannot be found.Error in : LaTeX failed to compile built_report.tex. shinyapps.io

Tags: deployment, latex, r-markdown, shinyapps

I developed shiny app that produces PDF files with in local machine without any hassle but when I upload it on **shinyapps.io**, it is successfully uploaded but it does not download pdf. Instead, it downloads **report.htm**, a blank file with **Failed-Server Problem**. When I look at the log, it points to **"Can't find Arial file"** and **do not find 'build_report.tex' file**. Help me out. I can't find solution.

YAML of my rmarkdown file is:

```
---
title: 
header-includes: \let\Begin\begin \let\End\end \newcommand{\Newrow}{\\} \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{multicol} \usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{tcolorbox} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{tgtermes}
  \usepackage{lscape}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
mainfont: Arial
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: pygments
    number_sections: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    includes:
      in_header: columns2.tex
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
monofont: Times New Roman
indent: yes
spacing: single
fig-caption: yes
geometry: left=1in, top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in
sansfont: Arial
always_allow_html: yes
classoption: openany
params:
  file: NA
  cmede: NA
  cklant: NA
  nmede: NA
  nklant: NA
---
```

[The log extracted from shinyapps.io is shown in image file below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMSxG.png)

Comment: I don't have `columns2.tex`, but other than that, your code works fine for me. I suggest 1) make sure that you have Arial installed on your computer 2) such old versions of xelatex sometimes had difficulties to find fonts by their name. You could either try with with the filename instead (e.g. `Arial.ttf` or whatever the file on your computer is called) or try with lualatex instead of xelatex

Comment: Thanks KG, I tried Verdana font and now this error disappeared but now there is another error:

Comment: Thanks KJ & samcarter, I tried Verdana font and now this error disappeared but now there is another error:

! LaTeX Error: Command `\eth' already defined.
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile built_report.tex.